# Babel 6 Typescript preset

Tags: javascript, typescript, babeljs

I'm looking for Babel preset for Typescript, but for Babel 6, not Babel 7. I cannot seem to find this module. Is TS preset not supported for Babel 6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using TypeScript 1.8+, the short answer would be that it's not supported on babel 6. babel 7 came with TS support as a selling point.

more details here https://matthewrwilton.wordpress.com/2016/03/18/typescript-to-es2015-es6-to-es5-via-babel-6/ and here https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/typescript-and-babel-7/

The amount of effort to make it work with babel 6 would be way superior to upgrading to babel 7